# How to count number of product in magento product listing?

Tags: magento, count, product

I am new to magento, i have to show total number of product of every category ! 
It shows only product of single page, but have to show all product of single category ? 
My code is below :)

```
<?php
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
// Changed By Umesh //


echo $_productCollection->count();

// End of Change by Umesh 

 ?>
```

It shows only 9, that is pagination per page product, but i have to show all number of product of certain category.

Answer (score 2):

**you can also use** `getSize()`

```
$cat_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
              ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $cat_id))
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

echo $collection->getSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the total no of products on product listing page (of that particular category), you can write below code

```
$currentCatId = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();

$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
  ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $currentCatId))
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

echo count($_testproductCollection);
```

Comment: and How to get current category id from list.phtml page ? @Manshvi

Comment: `$id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();` by this you will get the category_id on list page